# Change the Width of ComboboxItem in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I have set width of comboBox and comboBoxitem, but the width of comboBoxitem could not be set.

ComboboxItem always takes the width of combobox and the combobox must be editable for me.

What I have tried is:

```
ComboBox.Width = 110;
ComboBoxItem.Width = 400;
ComboBox.IsEditable = true;
```

I want combobox width to be 110 and comboboxitem width to be 400 and Iseditable must be true.

Comment: Hi, for `ComboBox`, the width of its drop-down menu is fixed, the same as the width of the `ComboBox` text box, and will not change due to the width of the internal elements. You can modify the width of the `ComboBoxItem`, but if it exceeds the width of the body, the content will be displayed in a horizontal scroll. Maybe you can explain why you are doing this, there may be other solutions

Comment: I have use this for dispalying Font family in UWP like in excel

Comment: Hi, If `IsEditable` is not enabled, the width of the `ComboBox` and the drop-down menu is calculated separately. But if `IsEditable` is enabled, the width of the drop-down menu will be forced to the width of the ComboBox, I checked the default style, but there is no way to change this. This should be the design of the control